# intersections between volumetric mesh and planes in cgal

Tags: intersection, cgal

I need to intersect a volumetric mesh (several tetrahedrons) with planes, what is the best way to do this?

I search for aabb trees but I dont know how to implement with volumetric meshs

Answer (score 0):

To use tetrahedra in the AABB-tree, you need to write a model of [AABBPrimitive](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classAABBPrimitive.html). Also, depending on what output you expect, you might want to use an AABB-tree of triangles (or even segments), by splitting the tetrahedra. If the input a tetmesh, you can even avoid duplicating shared triangles (segments).

Comment: thanks!!but I still dont know how to load a volumetric mesh

Comment: is it a CGAL tet mesh or a tet mesh generated by another software?

Comment: a tet mesh generated brt another software (gmsh)